# How do I transform my data?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The data table I have : Here Q3_*[ ]*_*[ ]* the 2nd variable is a SceneID and the 3rd variable is the # of products asked. So for a given SceneID they give 4 times to log their choice of ProductID and repeat the same for the next SceneID. So the response here is ProductID.

Lets say we have SceneID - 3,4 , # of times asked - 4 times, ProductID in responses - 9,108,4

```
ResponseID GYear FieldCode Q_3_1 Q_3_2 Q_3_3 Q_3_4 Q_6_1 Q_6_2 Q_6_3 Q_6_4
YAS101     2017  12        9      108   4    NULL  108   4     NULL  NULL
YAS102     2017  12        108    9    NULL  NULL  9     4     NULL  NULL
```

The output I want to see is ProductID in the label instead of order numbers like 1,2,3,4. So for Q_3_1 if a respondent answered 9 it should show as '1' in Q_3_9 else '0'

The desired output:

```
ResponseID GYear FieldCode Q_3_9 Q_3_108 Q_3_4 Q_6_9 Q_6_108 Q_6_4
YAS101     2017  12        1     1       1     0     1       1
YAS102     2017  12        1     1       0     1     0       1
```

The code I have now:

```
SELECT [ResponseID]
      ,[Gyear]
      ,[Fieldcode]
      ,CASE 
        WHEN q_3_1 = 9 or
             q_3_2 = 9 or
             q_3_3 = 9 then  1 else  0 END as q_3_9
      ,CASE 
        WHEN q_3_1 = 108 or
             q_3_2 = 108 or
             q_3_3 = 108 then 1 else  0 END as q_3_108
      ,CASE 
        WHEN q_3_1 = 4 or
             q_3_2 = 4 or
             q_3_3 = 4 then  1 else  0 END as q_3_4
      ,CASE 
        WHEN q_6_1 = 9 or
             q_6_2 = 9 or
             q_6_3 = 9 then  1 else  0 END as q_6_9
      ,CASE 
        WHEN q_6_1 = 108 or
             q_6_2 = 108 or
             q_6_3 = 108 then 1 else  0 END as q_6_108
      ,CASE 
        WHEN q_6_1 = 4 or
             q_6_2 = 4 or
             q_6_3 = 4 then  1 else  0 END as q_6_4
  FROM YAS_Data1
```

What I wanted to know was is there a better streamlined approach to this? As the data I have is very huge.

Thanks

Comment: This seems like aggregated data already, in a datamart perhaps. Is it normalized anywhere else--since it seems that is what you are trying to do, no?

Comment: This is a terrible way to manage your data.

Comment: This is just respondent level data I am trying to map the responses under the product.

Comment: @EdwardRusu well this how we get the data trying my best here. It was worse before I  would like to believe that I am trying more hard to makes this less terrible. :)

Comment: The best approach would be to normalize this. And wow are those column names hostile.